# C# access users' maibox through app-only authentication (using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices) - keep getting 403 error

Tags: c#, office365, console-application, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Since Microsoft prevents basic authentication, i have to rebuild my app that goes and downloads all attachments matching specific criteria from a mailbox in O365. This got me going on app-only authentication using client secret key as the app is a console app that runs on a timer few times a day and should need no user input.

My application is registered in AD and all permissions that i could think of have been added and granted by global admin.

I have setup and added appID, clientSecret,tenantID etc.

My code looks like this and it should work but i keep getting a 403 error.

Any help or suggestions on what to try next is appreciated.

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using Microsoft.Identity ;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;

using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace AuthenticationEWS
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0
            var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"])
                .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"])
                .WithTenantId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"])
                .Build();

            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

            try
            {
                var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
                var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
                ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
                ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId =
                    new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "labdata@ostara.com");

                //Include x-anchormailbox header
                ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "labdata@ostara.com");

                // Make an EWS call
                var folders = ewsClient.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView(10));
                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Folder: {folder.DisplayName}");
                }
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}");
            }

            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've even tried re-doing all the permissions but it doesn't look like it's a permissions thing but rather something in how i call the methods.

Comment: Where do you get a 403 error?  You have several URLs here.

Answer (score 1):

> My application is registered in AD and all permissions that i could think of have been added and granted by global admin.

There is only one permission you need for App Only authentication in EWS because of the change in the Azure Portal it's not easy to find so that is why they recommend you modify the manifest to add it in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

eg you need to have this permission

[image]

No other eg mail.read etc permission will work for EWS

The other thing that can cause a 403 is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-control-access-to-ews-in-exchange but if it worked previously it's still probably just you authentication.